# Javascript Replace specific special Character

Tags: javascript, regex, replace, special-characters

Hi i am having trouble to replace five "|||||" to one "|".

```
var ss = "123|||||456|||||789|||||";
var ww = ss.replace(/[|||||]\W/g, "|");
```

The output i get is

```
123|||456|||789|||
```

What are the correct RegEx i should write??
Thanks.

Comment: The square brackets `[]` syntax means "match any _one_ of the enclosed characters". (You're supposed to use it to list different characters.) When writing regex it can be handy to refer to a [regex guide](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do the following:

```
var ss = "123|||||456|||||789|||||";
console.log(ss.replace(/[|]{5}/g, "|"));
```

As mentioned in the comments, the `[]` defines a character class and matches any of the characters defined in it. for example `[a-z]` will match the lowercase alphabet.

However since you only need to match the pipe (`|`) character, you can remove the brackets and escape it like so:

```
console.log(ss.replace(/\|{5}/g, "|"));
```

It needs to be escaped by a `\` because the pipe is a special character in java script.
The curly notation `{5}` after the pipe defines how many of 'the previous' you want to match.